# BS4 Scraping Hidden Content

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have been stuck on this for awhile... I am trying to scrape the player name and projection from this site: https://www.fantasysportsco.com/Projections/Sport/MLB/Site/DraftKings/PID/793

The script is going to loop through the past by just going through all the PID's in a range, but that isnt the problem. The main problem is when I inspect the element I find the value is stored within this class:

```
<div class="salarybox expanded"...
```

which is located in the 5th position of my projectionsView list.

The scraper finds the projectionsView class fine but can't find anything within it.

When I goto view the actual HTML of the site it seems this content just doesn't exsist within it..

```
<div id="salData" class="projectionsView">
    <!-- Fill in with Salary Data -->
</div>
```

I'm super new to scraping and have successfully scraped everything else I need for my project just not this damn site... I think it may be because I have to sign up for the site? But either way the information is viewable without signing in so I figured I didnt need to use Selenium, and even if I did that wouldn't find it I don't think.

Anyway here's the code I have so far that is obviously returning a blank list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pandas as pd 
import os


url = "https://www.fantasysportsco.com/Projections/Sport/MLB/Site/DraftKings/PID/793"

uClient = uReq(url)
page_read = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_read, "html.parser")
salarybox = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"projectionsView"})
print(salarybox[4].findAll("div",{"class":"salarybox expanded"}))
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

The whole idea of the script is to just find the ppText of each "salarybox expanded" class on each page. I just want to know how to find these elements. Perhaps a different parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your url page, the `<div id="salData" class="projectionsView">`is re-write by the javascript, but `urllib.request` will get the whole response before running your callback, it means that the javascript generated content will be not in the response. Hence the div will be empty:

```
<div id="salData" class="projectionsView">
    <!-- Fill in with Salary Data -->
</div>
```

you better try with [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will work for this kind of dynamic website.

BTW, after you get the right response, you select `div` by `id`, it will be more specific:

```
salarybox = page_soup.find("div",{"id":"salData"})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! Appreciate it. I was hoping I wouldn't have to selenium but I think it will be fine. I'll write up some basic selenium code after lunch see if I can get a response. Never heard of splash tho? Will look into that as well

Comment: Mother of god. Selenium was way easy... Not sure why I didnt just try it before asking. Thanks for the advice anyway! I got it :)

Comment: @StuKruske COOL, CHEERS :)

Comment: Point for mentioning [splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Gonna take a look!